# Change shape of gradient progress bar

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

I have a gradient progress bar. My code is as follows:

CSS:

```
.progressbar {
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin:5px;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(-45deg,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%,transparent 25%, 
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%,transparent 75%) 
      left/30px 30px repeat-x,
      linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, yellow 50%, green 100%) left/var(--p,100%) fixed,
      lightgray;
  box-shadow:inset 0px -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation: change 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes change {
  from {background-position:0 0,left}
  to {background-position:30px 0,left}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="progressbar" style="width:80%;"></div>
```

I want to keep it as gradient bar only but just want to change shape of progress bar. I want  shape of progress bar as arrow as shown in image attached.How I can change shape of progress bar? [image: arrow_shape].

Comment: Could I suggest trimming your image down to reduce the wasted white-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a difficult one, and this workaround will not work if you don't use a solid background. But here's the trick done with pseudo elements. Hope it helps.

More info about CSS triangles [here](https://alvaromontoro.com/blog/67970/drawing-a-triangle-with-css).

```css
.progressbar {
    position: relative; /* for position absolute of pseudo element work */
    height: 56px;
    margin:5px;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(-45deg,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%,transparent 25%, 
        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%,transparent 75%) 
      left/30px 30px repeat,
      linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, yellow 50%, green 100%) left/var(--p,100%) fixed,
      lightgray;
  box-shadow:inset 0px -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  animation: change 1s linear infinite;
}

.progressbar:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 28px solid white; /* Your background color*/
  border-bottom: 28px solid white; /* Your background color*/
  border-left: 28px solid transparent;
}

.progressbar:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 28px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 28px solid transparent;
  border-left: 28px solid white; /* Your background color*/
}

@keyframes change {
  from {background-position:0 0,left}
  to {background-position:30px 0,left}
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar" style="width:80%;"></div>
```

Comment: How I can change width and height of this progress bar?

Comment: You can modify the element height (16px currently) but this height most not be an. odd number as you must to modify also the before and after pseudo elements borders to have the half of the height (currently 8px in snippet).

Comment: Which border border bottom or border left both? suppose I want to make height of progress bar as 56px then what will be the changes?

Comment: I edit my answer to fulfill you requirements. You need to modify all borders,  and also change the 'repeat-x' in the backgound of progress bar to 'repeat' as it doesn't get crop.

Comment: this fulfills my requirement. Just one question in your recent code. how you decided that border will be 28px?

Comment: As I told you before, all borders must set to half the height of progress bar for this workaround can work. That's why you must avoid odd heights, If you want a 30px height, all borders must be 15px, etc etc.

Comment: One last question. How I get rid off these white moving line in progress bar?

Comment: Do you want to remove all animation? So it should be a static gradient?

Comment: yes. I wamt to remove animation and these white animation lines as well

Comment: You should remove the first progress bar's linear gradient (it has 2) and remove the animation aswell.

Comment: Hi I have asked one more question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74392957/fixing-gap-and-alignment-in-progress-bar. request you to please have a look and help.